# Keyboard is selecting any view on activity or back activity after type any character

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-softkeyboard

I have to simple activities, the first have only one button that opens the second activity.
This second activity loads automatically the keyboard through a parameter on manifest (android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible") and has a text view and a button.
I had overridden the method: dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) to control the keys pressed on keyboard.

There are 2 problems:

1. If you type any character on keyboard it automatically kind select the button;
2. After 3 letters typed it will hide the keyboard and after press Back button to return to first activity (that has only one button) the button will be also selected.

Nothing must happen when you type any character on keyboard.

Below are all my codes (manifest, layouts and activities), I had removed all the functions of my application just to have the code clear only with the problem:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testbug"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.testbug.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.testbug.TestActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java (1º activity)**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btnStart;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**TestActivity.java (2º activity)**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

TextView tvType;
Button testButton;
int count = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_count);

    tvType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_type);
    testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    count++;
    if(count==6){
        hideKeyboard();
    }

    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}

private void hideKeyboard() {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)  getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
}
}
```

**Layouts:**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnStart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_count.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnTest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TestButton"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
    android:text="Press any key 3 times to Hide keyboard\n Then Press Back button. The same behavior of selection of button will happens on back activity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `automatically kind select the button`? Do you want button click automatically or just button should be focused?

Comment: @Rohit5k2, after click on any character the button is being selected automatically. It must not happen. Nothing should happen when type any character neither after go back to previous activity the button should not be selected.
I had tested it with focus (tried requestFocus) but seems that it is not related to focus. Seems to be something like when you use mouse or a tracker on android that you don't have the touch.

Comment: This is what I asked, what do you mean by selected? Please read my previous comment.

Comment: @Rohit5k2, I was editing and pressed enter before finished my comment. Please check my answer above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use `tvType.requestFocus();` at the end of method `hideKeyboard()`. This will keep focus on the edit text.

Comment: Don't work.
Seems that it is not related to focus. I tried to used requestFocus in many parts and didn't work.
This "selection" occurs if you type any word, not only after the hide keyboard.
The selection seems to be like when you use the device with a mouse, selecting buttons that will be clicked.

Comment: I don't clearly understand. Can you post a picture of what's happening on screen?

Comment: I added it to TinyPic:
http://tinypic.com/r/2uhmwdy/8
http://tinypic.com/r/6tk9aw/8

I had also investigate more the issue and the problem is that with the attribute 'android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"' at AndroidManifest it will open the activity with the keyboard opened and android expects that should be an Edit Text on activity to receive the keys pressed, but in my case I don't have it.
Because I override the dispatchKeyEvent() to receive the keys pressed and I use it in my application. So seems that android is not able to handle the keys pressed without having a edittext.

Comment: I had created a simple project that reproduces the issue:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=70317553185010262971&t=7031755318501026297126922